# List<Model> comes back as Null

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

new to ASP.net and have a question involving a model that has multiple variables of the same type.

I have Order model that can have 0 to n Detail models attached to it. When I POST the http request I get all the information for the Order except the Detail model always comes back as null. Or more specifically the ".count" method on the List is 0.

How can I get it to post all the Details for my Model?

Order Model:

```
public struct shipTo
{ 
public string id;
public string Line1;
public int PostalCode;
public string City;
public string State;
public string CountryCode;
}

namespace USS_EDIv2.Models
{


public class Order
{
   public Int64 SalesOrderNumber { get; set; }
    public Int64 PurchaseOrderNumber { get; set; }
    public Int64 BranchPlant { get; set; }
    public shipTo ShipTo;
    public Int64 Quantity { get; set; }
    public string UOM { get; set; }
    public List<Detail> Detail = new List<Detail>();
}



}
```

Detail Model:

```
namespace USS_EDIv2.Models
{

public class Detail
{
    public string LineNumber;
    public string GradeItem;
    public string Quantity;
    public string UOM;
    public string RequestDate;
    public string Status;

    public Detail()
    {

        LineNumber = "1";
        GradeItem = "1";
        Quantity = "1";
        UOM = "1";
        RequestDate = "1";
        Status = "1";
    }

}
}
```

Repository class:

```
namespace USS_EDIv2.Services
{

public class SalesRepository
{
    public DateTime currentTime = System.DateTime.Now;
    private const string CacheKey = "4041tmtTEST1337";
    public string xml;
    public int i;
    public Order[] GetAllSales()
    {
        var ctx = HttpContext.Current;

        if (ctx != null)
        {
            return (Order[])ctx.Cache[CacheKey];
        }

        return new Order[]
    {
        new Order
        {

        }
    };

    }

    public SalesRepository()
    {
        var ctx = HttpContext.Current;

        if (ctx != null)
        {
            if (ctx.Cache[CacheKey] == null)
            {
                var sales = new Order[]
                     {

                     };

                {
                };
                ctx.Cache[CacheKey] = sales;
                //ctx.Cache.Remove("4041tmtTEST1337");
            }
        }
    }

    public bool SaveSale(Order sales)
    {
        var ctx = HttpContext.Current;

        if (ctx != null)
        {
            try
            {

                var currentData = ((Order[])ctx.Cache[CacheKey]).ToList();


                currentData.Add(sales);

                ctx.Cache[CacheKey] = currentData.ToArray();

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                return false;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

}
}
```

And my Controller:

```
namespace USS_EDIv2.Controllers
{
public class NewOrderController : ApiController
{
    public DateTime currentTime = System.DateTime.Now;
    private SalesRepository salesRepository;
    public int i;

    public NewOrderController()
    {
        this.salesRepository = new SalesRepository();
    }

    public Order[] Get()
    {
        return salesRepository.GetAllSales();
    }


    public HttpResponseMessage Post(Order sale)
    {
        var ctx = HttpContext.Current;

        this.salesRepository.SaveSale(sale);

        var response = Request.CreateResponse<Order>  (System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Created, sale);

        return response;
    }



}

}
```

This is the XML data being requested:

```
<Order>

<SalesOrderNumber>1294288</SalesOrderNumber>

<PurchaseOrderNumber>81896</PurchaseOrderNumber>

<BranchPlant>9701</BranchPlant>

<ShipTo id="string">

<Line1>RAIL TRACK #769 SPOT 00</Line1>

<PostalCode>79765</PostalCode>

<City>MIDLAND COUNTY</City>

<State>TX</State>

<CountryCode>US</CountryCode>

</ShipTo>

<Quantity>75</Quantity>

<UOM>TN</UOM>



<Detail created="2015-12-14T13:59:57.84" action="Create">

<LineNumber>1.0</LineNumber>

<GradeItem>97010B00000</GradeItem>

<Quantity>25.000</Quantity>

<UOM>TN</UOM>

<RequestDate>2015-07-11</RequestDate>

<Status>Open</Status>

</Detail>


<Detail created="2015-12-14T13:59:57.84" action="Create">

<LineNumber>2.0</LineNumber>

<GradeItem>97010B00000</GradeItem>

<Quantity>25</Quantity>

<UOM>TN</UOM>

<RequestDate>2002-02-07</RequestDate>

<Status>Open</Status>

</Detail>


<Detail created="2015-05-22T02:29:50.78" action="Create">

<LineNumber>3.0</LineNumber>

<GradeItem>97010B00000</GradeItem>

<Quantity>25</Quantity>

<UOM>TN</UOM>

<RequestDate>2015-07-11</RequestDate>

<Status>Open</Status>

</Detail>

</Order>
```

And this is my current response:

```
<ArrayOfOrder xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<Order>
<ShipTo>
<Line1>RAIL TRACK #769 SPOT 00</Line1>
<PostalCode>79765</PostalCode>
<City>MIDLAND COUNTY</City>
<State>TX</State>
<CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
</ShipTo>
************HERE LIES THE PROBLEM
<Detail/>
************
<SalesOrderNumber>1294288</SalesOrderNumber>
<PurchaseOrderNumber>81896</PurchaseOrderNumber>
<BranchPlant>9701</BranchPlant>
<Quantity>75</Quantity>
<UOM>TN</UOM>
</Order>
</ArrayOfOrder>
```

I also have no control over changing the format of the incoming xml data. Any pointer in the right direction would be helpful please.

Debug:

[debug] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTkoy.jpg)

Comment: `Detail model always comes back as null. Or more specifically the ".count" method on the List is 0`  These statements would seem to contradict eachother

Comment: shipTo should be a class, not a struct.  Your Fields should be Properties — they need a "get - set".

Comment: You notice a difference between your `Order` and `Details` classes? Syntactically speaking

Comment: When you step through this whole process in your debugger, where exactly is the "detail" data lost?

Comment: `public List<Detail> Detail = new List<Detail>();`  you should consider renaming this to `Details` to indicate its a collection of `Detail`, not a single instance.

Comment: Amy I tried that and it then assumes the incoming data has a block called <Details> </Details> where the Detail data resides.

Comment: @JamesN I think @Amy meant `public List<Detail> Details = new List<Detail>();`

Comment: David when I step through my debugger it always says  count = 0 for my Detail object at all steps. I included a picture of the debug in the post.

Comment: @JamesN: You may need to create a custom serializer/deserializer for that XML.  If those `Detail` nodes aren't wrapped in something like a `Details` node then the default serializer might not make sense of it.

Comment: @BviLLe Thats how I did it and it expects the incoming POST to have a <Details> block which it doesnt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay,

So I solved this by copying the XML data onto my clipboard, creating a new class and then going to Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste XML as classes

and it came up with this:

```
namespace USS_EDIv2.Models
{
public class Orders
{
}
/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class Order
{

    private uint salesOrderNumberField;

    private uint purchaseOrderNumberField;

    private ushort branchPlantField;

    private OrderShipTo shipToField;

    private byte quantityField;

    private string uOMField;

    private OrderDetail[] detailField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public uint SalesOrderNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return this.salesOrderNumberField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.salesOrderNumberField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public uint PurchaseOrderNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return this.purchaseOrderNumberField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.purchaseOrderNumberField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public ushort BranchPlant
    {
        get
        {
            return this.branchPlantField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.branchPlantField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public OrderShipTo ShipTo
    {
        get
        {
            return this.shipToField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.shipToField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public byte Quantity
    {
        get
        {
            return this.quantityField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.quantityField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string UOM
    {
        get
        {
            return this.uOMField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.uOMField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Detail")]
    public OrderDetail[] Detail
    {
        get
        {
            return this.detailField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.detailField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class OrderShipTo
{

    private string line1Field;

    private uint postalCodeField;

    private string cityField;

    private string stateField;

    private string countryCodeField;

    private string idField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string Line1
    {
        get
        {
            return this.line1Field;
        }
        set
        {
            this.line1Field = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public uint PostalCode
    {
        get
        {
            return this.postalCodeField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.postalCodeField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string City
    {
        get
        {
            return this.cityField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.cityField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string State
    {
        get
        {
            return this.stateField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.stateField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string CountryCode
    {
        get
        {
            return this.countryCodeField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.countryCodeField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string id
    {
        get
        {
            return this.idField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.idField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class OrderDetail
{

    private decimal lineNumberField;

    private string gradeItemField;

    private decimal quantityField;

    private string uOMField;

    private System.DateTime requestDateField;

    private string statusField;

    private System.DateTime createdField;

    private string actionField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public decimal LineNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return this.lineNumberField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.lineNumberField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string GradeItem
    {
        get
        {
            return this.gradeItemField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.gradeItemField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public decimal Quantity
    {
        get
        {
            return this.quantityField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.quantityField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string UOM
    {
        get
        {
            return this.uOMField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.uOMField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType = "date")]
    public System.DateTime RequestDate
    {
        get
        {
            return this.requestDateField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.requestDateField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string Status
    {
        get
        {
            return this.statusField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.statusField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public System.DateTime created
    {
        get
        {
            return this.createdField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.createdField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string action
    {
        get
        {
            return this.actionField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.actionField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Just in case anyone ever stumbles across this problem. What was giving me hours of headache took 3 clicks to solve... Thanks all for your replies.

Comment: Nice of you to let others know of the solution! You may want to set your answer as accepted so other users my know this is the correct answer

Comment: huuum, I see. Didn't know that, sorry then :)

Comment: No worries Francis! Just glad to have this solved and hopefully help others in the future